# Find $f \circ g$, $g \circ f$, $f \circ f$, $g \circ g$ where $f(x)=-1+|x-2|$ and $g(x)=2-|x|$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions, function-and-relation-composition

If $f(x)=-1+|x-2|;0\leq x\leq4$ and 
$g(x)=2-|x|;-1\leq x\leq3$
Then find $f \circ g(x),g \circ f(x),f \circ f(x),g \circ g(x)$
[image]

---

In the above figure the red graph shows $g(x)$ and the blue graph shows $f(x)$.
The domain of $f(x)$ is $0\leq x\leq4$ and the domain of $g(x)$ is $-1\leq x\leq3$.
I found the domain of $f \circ g(x)$,it is the intersection of $-1\leq x\leq3$ and $0\leq g(x)\leq 4$ i.e. the intersection of $-1\leq x\leq3$ and $-2\leq x\leq 2$.So its domain is $-1\leq x\leq 2$.
then  found the domain of $g \circ f(x)$,it is the intersection of $0\leq x\leq4$ and $-1\leq f(x)\leq 3$ i.e. the intersection of $0\leq x\leq4$ and $-2\leq x\leq 6$.So its domain is $0\leq x\leq 4$.
then i found the domain of $f \circ f(x)$,it is the intersection of $0\leq x\leq4$ and $0\leq f(x)\leq 4$ i.e. the intersection of $0\leq x\leq4$ and $-3\leq x\leq 1\cup 3\leq x\leq 7$.So its domain is $0\leq x\leq 1\cup 3\leq x\leq 4$.
then i found the domain of $g \circ g(x)$,it is the intersection of $-1\leq x\leq3$ and $-1\leq g(x)\leq 3$ i.e. the intersection of $-1\leq x\leq3$ and $-3\leq x\leq 3$.So its domain is $-1\leq x\leq 3$.
Now i found $f \circ g(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             -1-x  & -1 \leq x \leq 0 \\
             \\ x-1, &0<x\leq2 \\
             \\ 
             \end{array}
   \right.$ which i got correct.
I found $g \circ f(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             x+1  & 0 \leq x \leq 2 \\
             \\ -x+5, &2\leq x\leq 4 \\
             \\ 
             \end{array}
   \right.$
.But my book says this is wrong and correct $g \circ f(x)$ is
$g \circ f(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             x+1  & 0 \leq x <1 \\
             \\3-x&1\leq x\leq 2 \\
             \\x-1&2<x\leq 3  \\
             \\ -x+5, &3 <x\leq 4 \\
             \\ 
             \end{array}
   \right.$I dont know where have i gone wrong.
I found $f \circ f(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             x  & 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\
             \\ x-6, &3\leq x\leq 4 \\
             \\ 
             \end{array}
   \right.$.But my books says this is wrong.And the correct $f \circ f(x)$ is $f \circ f(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             x  & 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\
             \\ -x+4, &3\leq x\leq 4 \\
             \\ 
             \end{array}
   \right.$.I dont know where have i gone wrong.
I found $g \circ g(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             x+4  & -1 \leq x \leq 0 \\
             \\ x, &0\leq x\leq 3 \\
             \\ 
             \end{array}
   \right.$ But my books says this is wrong and the correct gog(x) is
$g \circ g(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             -x  & -1 \leq x \leq 0 \\
             \\ x, &0< x\leq 2 \\
             \\ 4-x,&2<x\leq 3\\
             \end{array}
   \right.$I dont know where have i gone wrong.
Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: Use  `$f \circ g$` for the composition $f \circ g$, that looks nicer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will look at $g\circ f$ for you only, maybe this would help you correcting the other parts.

In general when doing such exercises you should particular attention to when the functions or their derivatiaves change sign. For $f(x)$ these points on the domain are $x=1,2,3$. Here hence you should look at four different ranges: $0<x<1$, $1<x<2$, $2<x<3$ and $3<x<4$. When feeding $f(x)$, i.e. the range you should then care only about the rule of $g(x)$.

Let start with the $0<x<1$. Here $0<f(x)=1-x<1$ therefore $g(f(x))=2-|1-x|$ or that $g(f(x))=2-(1-x)=1+x$.

Now lets look at $1<x<2$, here we have $-1<f(x)=1-x<0$, therefore $g(f(x))=2-|1-x|$ or that $g(f(x))=2-(x-1)=3-x$.

also for $2<x<3$ we have $-1<f(x)=-3+x<0$ hence $g(f(x))=2-|-3+x|$ or that $g(f(x))=2-(3-x)=-1+x$.

and finally for $3<x<4$ we have $0<f(x)=-3+x<1$ hence $g(f(x))=2-|-3+x|$ or that $g(f(x))=2-(-3+x)=5-x$.

Doing similar steps for the rest of the functions you should be able to obtain the correct results.

Comment: I understood the method posted by you,thank you.And i found the remaining compositions also.But i do not understand why we give attention to the points where functions and "their derivatives" changes sign.Why derivatives sign change points are also important.Is this rule of sign change applicable in composition of modulus functions only or to composition of every type of functions?@Math-fun

Comment: you are welcome, I am happy you got it all done :-) In the case of absolute value function, the change in the derivative is particularly important since you observe a sharp "change" in the path/form of the function.